# Correlation, Linear Regression, and Minimizing Cost

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation, linear-regression, mean-square-error

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with correlation coefficient $\rho$, then linear regression tells us that, is we wish to minimize the mean square error, then the best linear approximation $\hat{Y}$ (resp $\hat{X}$) of $Y$ ($X$) as a function of $X$ ($Y$) satisfies
$$\frac{\hat{Y}-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y} = \rho\frac{X-\mu_X}{\sigma_X},$$
$$\frac{\hat{X}-\mu_X}{\sigma_X} = \rho\frac{Y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}.$$

I want to highlight here that in BOTH cases, the slope (as a function of the normalized variables) is $\rho$, which reflects the fact that $\rho$ is a symmetric function of $X$ and $Y$. Now, if someone were to ask me for the equation of the line of best fit between $X$ and $Y$, WITHOUT mentioning that we want to minimize mean squared error, my naive guess would be that whatever slope the line of best fit has for $Y$ vs $X$, the line of best fit for $X$ vs $Y$ should have the inverse slope, that is (assuming $X$ and $Y$ are normalized for simplicity):
$$\hat{Y} = aX \quad \iff \quad \hat{X} = \frac{1}{a}Y,$$
with the case $a=0$ being left undetermined.
This was my first naive attempt, but after some reflection I realized why this doesn't need to be the case, both on a conceptual level and on an algebraic level. Basically, my confusion was resting on the following logic:
$$(\hat{Y} = \rho X \quad \& \quad \hat{Y} \approx Y) \implies  Y \approx \rho X \iff X \approx \frac{1}{\rho}Y \implies \hat{X} = \frac{1}{\rho}Y,$$
and written this way it is clear that the mistake is at the $\hat{Y} \approx Y$ step.

Now, I'm saying all of this to finally get to the following question: is there a (natural, useful) way of defining $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$ so that they do satisfy the naive logic I presented? Perhaps by changing the cost function from mean squared error to something else, and/or by replacing the correlation coefficient by some other quantity $\rho'$ satisfying $\rho'(X,Y) = \frac{1}{\rho'(Y,X)}$?

$\textbf{tldr:}$ Can we reformulate linear regression to make $\hat{Y} = \rho{X} \iff \hat{X} = \frac{1}{\rho}Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the cost function from the sum of the squared vertical distances to the sum of the square *perpendicular* distances makes the problem symmetric in the way you describe:

[image: ols vs. tls]

This is generally known as [Total least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares). See the discussion on Cross Validated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/how-to-perform-orthogonal-regression-total-least-squares-via-pca/136597#136597).